# Строка: Вывод слов, заканчивающихся на определенные буквы

Tags: c++

Строка: Вывод слов, заканчивающихся на определенные буквы. Я написал подобие кода , но оно не работает.Напишите , где у меня ошибка.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    const int N = 50;
    char str[N];
    cout << "Enter a string:\n";
    cin.getline(str, N);
 
    char sep[] ="! .,;:?()-";
    char Ptr;
    char* next = NULL;
    Ptr = strtok(str, sep, &next);
    while (Ptr != NULL)
    {
        int len = strlen(Ptr);
        if (Ptr[len - 1] == 'd' && Ptr[len - 2] == 'r' && Ptr[len>=2]) 
        cout << Ptr << endl;
        Ptr = strtok(NULL, sep, &next);
    }
}
```

Comment: `char* Ptr;` ... `if (len>=2 && Ptr[len - 1] == 'd' && Ptr[len - 2] == 'r')`

Comment: спасибо))))))))